# Invalidate ASP.NET Identity Authentication Token upon Signout

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I've observed a behavior of ASP.NET Identity when a user signs out. Upon calling `SignOutAsync` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`, it clears the value of the cookie from the user's browser. But still if I put the token value back as it was before by editing the browser cookie, **user gets logged in again**.

Is there a way to invalidate the Tokens permanently so they can't be re-used after signing out?

Comment: You can store all valid tokens in a db table, and when you decide that the token is invalid, you just delete it from the table. Of course you will need to store the expiration time of the token also, and refresh it as needed. We had a similar problem on a project I worked and thats the way we solved it.

Comment: @Dekay how would you add this custom layer of authentication in `ASP.NET Identity`? Could you be able to share some codes or at least a direction to look?